# Use .Find so that it recognizes cells identically

Tags: excel, vba

I have two worsheet with names. I use ".find" parameters to find similary names on my worsheets. But the problem is some names have a similary part as other.

Exemple : I've got "Jean" and "Jean marc" on my worksheet A and on worksheet B just "Jean". When i compare, the result on worksheet C is "Jean, Jean marc".

My code :

```
For j = line To 10000 Step 1
    
    name = Feuil1.Cells(j, 5)
    If name <> "" Then
        If Feuil2.Range("A:A").Find(nom) Is Nothing Then
            Feuil1.Cells(j, 5).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Else
            Feuil3.Cells(n, 1).Value = Feuil1.Cells(j, 5).Value
            Feuil3.Cells(n, 2).Value = Feuil1.Cells(j, 10).Value
            n = n + 1
         End If
        
    End If
Next j
```

Comment: What is the question? It is very unclear what you want to do. Please give some example input data and expected output so it is easier to understand. Explain what exactly you want your code to do.

Comment: Using `Find()` without explicitly providing values for lookAt, lookIn, etc can be very unreliable, and you can't depend on it doing exactly what you expect (such as partial vs. exact match)